# How can I expand an EditText when it is not focused?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm doing a message view like whats app and I want my EditText in the bottom to have the "send" button/icon if it's focused and if it's not, then hide/delete that button and expand the edit text. I don't know how to do the the expand and delete thing in run time. If anyone has some clue I would be really thankful.

Comment: Please add an example of what you already have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OnFocusListener` to trigger your desired events whenever focus of `EditText` changes.

Use `setVisibility` to hide and show your `Button`, and change width of `EditText` via `getLayoutParams().width`

```
m_editText.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if (hasFocus) {
                m_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                m_editText.getLayoutParams().width=400;
            } else {
                m_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                m_editText.getLayoutParams().width=200;
            }
        });
```

You can also turn your size to `dp` with:

```
TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, YOUR_SIZE_HERE, getApplication().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```